# How to save and restore actual viewport parameters/preferences on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I would like to be able to save and restore all the viewport parameters (like current scroll position both vertical and horizontal and current zoom level - maybe anything else) on mobile browsers (or at least on mobile Safari). The scenario goes like this:

1. save parameters
2. do something with viewport
3. restore the parameters **exactly** to the previous state (1)

How can I do it please?